# Frequent crashes in graphics-intense applications - is my GPU dying?

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure, gpu, crash

I recently started getting strange crashes in games such as Dark Souls or GRIP: Combat Racing. My GTX 1080 should in theory be able to handle these with no problems. The crashes usually appear randomly after some time of playing.

What makes me think it is the GPU is that apps have been crashing at the same time. For example: Dark Souls and OBS Studio. Sometimes, after a while, the whole GPU driver seems to crash: Screen goes black, then only the main screen but not the second monitor comes back, with compositing stuff such as transparency no longer working.

I took out and cleaned the card as well as I could, but that didn't seem to change anything.

I decided to completely reinstall Windows to rule out software issues. Then, after installing drivers, I ran Furmark, which crashed after a few seconds, and tried to run GRIP, which crashed shortly after starting a race.

I've had this GPU for only about a year, and this never happened before a week ago, though I've bought it used.

Some system info:

- OS Name  Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Version    10.0.19045 Build 19045
- System Type  x64-based PC Processor  AMD Ryzen 5 5500, 3600 Mhz, 6
- Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s) BaseBoard Manufacturer  Micro-Star
- International Co., Ltd BaseBoard Product B450 GAMING PLUS MAX (MS-7B86)
- Installed Physical Memory (RAM)  16,0 GB Adapter
- Description  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080 Adapter RAM (1.048.576) bytes
- Driver Version   31.0.15.3640 Resolution 1920 x 1080 x 60 hertz

Here are some example crash reports copied from event viewer:

> Faulting application name: DARKSOULS.exe, version: 1.0.2.0, time
> stamp: 0x557f2fd0 Faulting module name: d3d9.dll, version: 0.0.0.0,
> time stamp: 0x5b71c6f0 Exception code: 0xc0000005
>
> Faulting application name: obs-browser-page.exe, version: 0.0.0.0,
> time stamp: 0x63b8a351 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
> 10.0.19041.2130, time stamp: 0xb0fac6c9 Exception code: 0xe0000008
>
> Faulting application name: dwm.exe, version: 10.0.19041.746, time
> stamp: 0x6be51595 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
> 10.0.19041.2130, time stamp: 0xb0fac6c9 Exception code: 0xc00001ad
>
> A TDR has been detected. The application must close. Error code: 7
> (pid=7600 tid=3384 furmark.exe 32bit)
>
> Faulting application name: FurMark.exe, version: 1.35.0.0, time stamp:
> 0x64933012 Faulting module name: nvoglv32.dll, version: 31.0.15.3640,
> time stamp: 0x649602c9 Exception code: 0xc0000409
>
> Faulting application name: Grip-Win64-Shipping.exe, version: 4.17.2.0,
> time stamp: 0x62511845 Faulting module name: nvwgf2umx.dll, version:
> 31.0.15.3640, time stamp: 0x6496040f Exception code: 0xc0000005

For the GRIP crash, an Unreal Engine error popup said something like "low level fatal error, but it went away before I could copy it. From monitoring GPU sensors with GPU-Z, it seems that the crash happens during a brief GPU Load spike:

[image: GPU-Z readings]

The PerfCap reason is "vRel".

How can I diagnose this further? Is there any hope for my graphics card? Is there anything I can do to fix this without having to replace it?

Edit: I just realized that since I have the MSI version of the 1080 (specifically GAMING X 8G), it is stock-overclocked. I removed the OC by enabling Nvidia Debug Mode, and so far GRIP seems to be stable, with GPU load spikes staying under 100%. But GRIP is hardly the most demanding game, and I am pretty sure that I already had Debug Mode enabled when the crashes started happening. I may have disabled it by resetting my driver settings in the initial troubleshooting. It still seems weird that a GPU running at stock overclock would be so unstable.

Edit 2: I'm using a Corsair CS650M PSU from around 2015, used in the previous build. Maybe the GPU simply doesn't get enough power? I'd certainly rather replace the PSU than the GPU. According to Newegg PSU calculator my system only requires 600W, but I realize that my PSU is quite old, and according to some sources, wattage degradation is a thing.

Comment: Something else that simply degrades over time is your PC's PSU.

Comment: Hmm, well the PSU, along with the case, is the oldest part of my system, having been used in a previous build since as far back as around 2016. The GPU spike does seem to coincide with a peak in power draw. Certainly conceivable that the PSU just can't keep up with the demand. Idk enough about this topic to say whether this is consistent with the kinds of crashes and errors I'm getting though.

Comment: PSU brownout can cause a whole host of semi-random errors. The GPU is the only thing that draws significantly from the 12V line and if that is where the PSU is failing then that could cause the problem. Above all else the PSU is typically one of the cheaper and easier parts to replace, especially considering GPU prices these days. Capacitors in switch mode power supplies are prone to degradation and failure over time.